# Building infinite rotating images carrousel with Velocity.js,

Tags: jquery, slider, velocity.js

I'm trying to build an infinite rotating images carrousel, attempt can be seen here: [http://2017.app.envisic.nl/wordpress](http://2017.app.envisic.nl/wordpress/)

I want the 4 horizontal bars (class="mosaic-bar") with tiles (class="tile") to infintately slide to the right at different speeds. When the user resizes, all images should be resized accordingly. That works. However, the infinate slide does not. My approach is that each bar should be animated to slide 1 x the width of a tile to the right. When that is finished, the tile on the most right should be moved to the left and then the whole thing starts over again. What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var slideInterval;
var winHeight = 0;
var tileDim = 0;

function tileSlider() {

    winHeight = $(window).height();
    tileDim = winHeight / 4;

    //Set tile dimensions
    $(".tile").css( {'height': tileDim + 'px', 'width': tileDim + 'px'} );

    //Animate each bar to slide right
    function slide() {
        $(".mosaic-bar").each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
            var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 2000
            var self = this;

            //Move each bar to the right 1 tile
            function s() {
                $(self).velocity(   {
                                    translateX: tileDim 
                                } , { 
                                    duration: t, 
                                    easing: "linear", 
                                    complete: function() {
                                        //On complete, move tile on the right to the left
                                        $(self).append($(self).children(".tile").first());
                                        //Reset the animation
                                        $(self).removeAttr('style');
                                    }
                                });
            }

            //Then call the function to instantly start the animation, and then loop it
            s();
            slideInterval = setInterval(function() { s(); }, t + 1);
        });
    }
    slide();
};


tileSlider();

$(window).resize(function() {
    tileSlider();
});
```

});